# What is the correct way to install PycURL inside venv

Tags: python-3.x, pycurl, python-venv

Having multiple macbooks with different OS versions, I have difficulty distributing my Python3.6 project which uses PycURL as `libcurl` installed may be compiled with different options. The most common error I get on different machines is: `ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)`

I thought that it'd be more reasonable to distribute `venv` preconfigured with all dependencies, but how to correctly install PycURL inside venv? As I understand, I should build it myself and link with the proper `libcurl.so`, which should be added to `venv` as well, right? Is there anything I should be aware of or take into account?